# Ability to set audio position before playback

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

While beginnning audio playback, I need the ability to set the position in the audio file from where to begin the playback.

Please guide me with the API's to be used for this functionality.

Until now I have been using `SoundEffectInstance` for audio playback, but I do not see an option to set the audio playback position in that.

Comment: Irrespective of the "-1", I require the answer quite urgently. I will like to know which Windows audio playback API supports this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to play audio, see [Media for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Without knowing which one you're using, it's a bit difficult to answer the question.

The [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class has a settable property for [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that could serve your purpose.